# SciKitlearn ColumnTransformer TypeError: Cannot clone object. You should provide an instance of scikit-learn estimator instead of a class

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Attempting to work with something that looks a little like this:

```
  CATEGORY | NUMBER VALUE  | ID

   FRUIT   |      15       |  XCD

  VEGGIES  |      12       |  ZYK



from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
data = data.iloc[:,:].values
enc = LabelEncoder()
data[:,0]=enc .fit_transform(data[:,0])
data
```

### **Output:**

```
array([[1, 15, 'XCD'],
       [2, 12, 'ZYK']])
```

---

**Then...**

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encode',OneHotEncoder,[0])],remainder='passthrough')
dataset = np.array(ct.fit_transform(data))
```

gives

```
TypeError: Cannot clone object. You should provide an instance of scikit-learn estimator instead of a class.
```

Answer (score 14):

I believe I resolved this one. The TypeError is pretty self explanatory and I'm ashamed for not recognizing this before posting my question. Essentially I just needed to create an instance of the OneHotEncoder class. Adding one line as shown in the code below resolved my situation. Thank you!

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
oHe = OneHotEncoder()
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encode',oHe,[0])],remainder='passthrough')
dataset = np.array(ct.fit_transform(data))
```

Comment: It saved a lot of my time, sometimes even simple mistakes need written solutions. Thanks a ton for jotting it down.

Comment: You have to pass an object of the transformer/estimator: Pass `OneHotEncoder()` instead of `OneHotEncoder` -> `ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encode',OneHotEncoder(),[0])],remainder='passthrough')`

Answer (score 6):

I had faced similar issue when fitting `RandomizedSearchCV` in `xgboost`. Just like said above, I also felt ashamed for not identifying this simple error. I typed

```
regressor = xgboost.XGBRegressor
```

instead of

```
regressor = xgboost.XGBRegressor().
```

After reading here, I spent sometime to identify this error and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

**After performing these steps:**

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
data = data.iloc[:,:].values
enc = LabelEncoder()
data[:,0]=enc .fit_transform(data[:,0])
data
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array([[1, 15, 'XCD'],
   [2, 12, 'ZYK']])
```

*Then go for these commands instead of using what you have used there:*

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer(
transformers=[('encode',OneHotEncoder(categories='auto'),[0])],
remainder='passthrough')

dataset = np.array(ct.fit_transform(data))
dataset
```

Then your code will not throw an error

**OUTPUT**:

```
array([['1.0', '0.0', '15', 'XCD'],
   ['0.0', '1.0', '12', 'ZYK']], dtype='<U32')
```

[image: image displaying above code block and output working]