# SciKitlearn GaussianProcessRegressor TypeError: Cannot clone object. You should provide an instance of scikit-learn estimator instead of a class

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, gaussian-process

Trying to fit GaussianProcess model using train test split :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, RationalQuadratic as RQ, ConstantKernel as C
```

Then :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_scaled, y_scaled, test_size = 0.3, random_state=0)

kernel = C
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=4)
gp.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Then error looks like this :

```
TypeError: Cannot clone object. You should provide an instance of scikit-learn estimator instead of a class.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SciKitlearn ColumnTransformer TypeError: Cannot clone object. You should provide an instance of scikit-learn estimator instead of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62330259/scikitlearn-columntransformer-typeerror-cannot-clone-object-you-should-provide)

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the full error trace